# What is "defun" in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I sometimes see the **defun** function in Smarty. Unfortunately the file compiler.defun.php is not documented, neither could I google anything usefull. So what does defun mean, and what exactly should it do?

Reading the code I reason that it is some sort of function creation, but I can´t think of why someone would define functions withhin a smarty template. Google results often mention iteration recursions, but without giving an example on how defun is related to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that `defun` is similar (or the same) as [`function`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl). My guess is that `defun` is some yoda-speak for "function definition".

I'd used that for generating a nav container, asymmetric and dynamic in nature, that required to copy some boilerplate html lists with simple mods to their class attributes. Actually I've found something similar [example of generating a nested menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996878/1105871). Also I've used it to create sort of ad hoc simple view helpers for ZF2 forms.

One could argue whether declaring functions in templates makes for a readable and/or maintainable code, but it's an option.

Comment: [defun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defun) historically comes from "***de***fine ***fun***ction" (no yoda about it), a LISP-y term. There are other "def*" forms as well in such language families.

Comment: Great, thank you! Did you encounter any performance issues as I would imagine in an eval()-like-construct, or is defun a convenient alternative to {include}?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it to be honest, but I can't imagine `include` to be faster (in the recursion scenarios mentioned) than `function`, since it has to, at some point, fetch the template from the disk. I think consecutive `include` call for the same template could be cached with something like opcache, but it's still more than defining a function. I did come across an interesting discussion on smarty forums touching this subject: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=18153  . I guess it all depends on a use case, but for nested menus I'd go with recursive `function` calls.